# Check If List Contains All Elements Of An Array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am trying to check if a List contains all values that are saved in an Array.

Here is my code:

```
List<PlayingCard> playerDeck = new ArrayList<>();
playerDeck.add(PlayingCard.METAL);
playerDeck.add(PlayingCard.METAL);

public boolean canBuild(Item item) {
    return playerDeck.containsAll(Arrays.asList(item.requiredCards()));
}
```

```
public enum Item {
    ...

    public PlayingCard[] requiredCards() {
        return new PlayingCard[] {
            PlayingCard.METAL,
            PlayingCard.METAL,
            PlayingCard.METAL
        };
    }
}
```

My current canBuild() method won't work like this.

```
playerDeck = [Metal] requiredCards = [Metal, Metal]
playerDeck.containsAll(requiredCards) == true
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't declare one of your enums correctly.  And it is unclear whether you were trying to executed method in a static context.  Try the following:

```
enum PlayingCard {
    METAL
}

enum Item {
    FOO;

    public PlayingCard[] requiredCards() {
        return new PlayingCard[] { PlayingCard.METAL,
                PlayingCard.METAL, PlayingCard.METAL };
    }
}

static List<PlayingCard> playerDeck = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    playerDeck.add(PlayingCard.METAL);
    playerDeck.add(PlayingCard.METAL);
    Item foo = Item.FOO;
    System.out.println(canBuild(foo));

}

public static boolean canBuild(Item item) {
    return playerDeck
            .containsAll(Arrays.asList(item.requiredCards()));
}
```

UPDATE:

```
 List<Integer> a = List.of(1,1,1);
 List<Integer> b = List.of(1,1);
 List<Integer> c = List.of(1,1,1);
 List<Integer> d = List.of(1,2,1);
 List<Integer> e = List.of(1,1,2);
 System.out.println(a.equals(b)); //false different count
 System.out.println(a.equals(c)); //true same numbers and count
 System.out.println(a.equals(d));// false same count, different numbers
 System.out.println(a.equals(e)); // false same numbers and count, different order
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question right. My problem is that my current canBuild method doesn't take the number of elements into account. So if playerDeck only contains one METAL item and item.requiredCards contains 3x METAL, it will still return true. So containsAll cannot be used in this case. However, I am not sure how I should implement this method else. Thank you for trying though

Comment: If you have two lists and they have the same values in them in the same order, they will compare as equal, if that helps.

Comment: Yes, but how can I compare two lists with a different amount of the same elements then?

Comment: One has Metal, the other has Metal, Metal. They shouldn't compare as equal.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but actually the order doesn't matter. This is for a game where you can build certain items if you have enough resources for it. So I don't think that this is going to work here.

Comment: Then you can use `Collections.sort` to guarantee the same list of elements are equal regardless of order.

Comment: equals still won't do it, because there can also be more elements than needed. For example an axe needs 3x METAL. if the playingDeck consists of METAL, PLASTIC, METAL, METAL it should still work and the three times METAL of playingDeck should be removed after the item was crafted. Then playerDeck will only consist of PLASTIC.

Comment: My last suggestion is to assign values to each object.  The object could be a class with a certain value. Then when you compare them, sum up the list of the items` values and see if the sums are equal.  You could structure this however you want.  But other than that, I have no solution.  And that restriction should have been part of your original question.  Otherwise folks will never get the answer right.